# Как надо записывать значение оператора цикла for в оператор if?

Tags: c++, переменные, visual-studio-2017, библиотеки

В самом внизу ссылка , по которой я писал код
Если можете то , объясните  , буду благодарен

Вот код , он работает но я неуверен что правильно

Вывод в консоли : x = 7
i = 5.20345e+174

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<iostream>
 #include<math.h>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
 int main()
{
   double a, x;
    cout << " x = ";
 cin >> x;
   int i;
   for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++); - как это записать в if     правильно
  if (        ) ;
  
 a = pow((-1), i + 1)*pow(x, 2 * i) / 2 * i*(2 * i - 1);
 cout << " i = " << a << endl;
 system("pause");
 return 0;
 }
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oubWk.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Вы ничего на русском не вводите и не выводите, так что все эти пляски с бубном

```
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
SetConsoleCP(1251);
```

вам пока ни к чему. Далее, все вроде бы ничего... но вы же **не знаете** радиусы! То, что вы знаете — H и D, кстати, их надо ввести в программу:

```
double H, D;
cout << "H = "; cin >> H;
cout << "D = "; cin >> D;
```

Теперь посмотрим, что можно сделать... Пусть радиус большого круга — R, внутреннего — r. Тогда получается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решая эту систему уравнений, легко найти

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так что площадь кольца

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В С++ это запишется как (с учетом вашего `const double PI=3.141592653589793;`)

```
double S = PI*H*H*(D+1)/(D-1);
```

Думаю, вывод `S` вы уже напишете самостоятельно? Тот, что написан у вас, обрывается на полусло....
Еще не хватает проверок на правильность вводимых данных — что H и D положительны, что D больше 1... Опять же — это вам домашнее задание :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , выходит что ещё кроме этого нужно записать в конце площадь кольца языком с++ ?https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCWxR.png

Comment: Я ее вам записал — вон же: `double S = ...`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Спасибо здесь принимает форму принятого ответа (птичка слева)...

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11nWUBzJ1LxxfZlRx8YvjgPJ1Rh55mqf2/view?usp=drivesdk Я отредактировал  код , но есть 2 ошибки

Comment: Как их устранить ?

Comment: Вы бы сделали доступ для всех, а?... Посмотреть ваш код невозможно.

Comment: И в чом проблема?

Comment: Я вам надал доступ

Comment: Вам не кажется, что **сначала** нужно вве6сти числа, а **потом** уже выполнять с ними расчеты?

Comment: Тот код что на фотографии правильный или нужны изменения ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lB1FWlJMRzFNlXRULnr8vwdzstVcy1Vb/view?usp=drivesdk
Я записал формулу обчисления площи кольца но выбивают ошибки

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qQl8CHfUKBWiLwEQWMAXBiejg2YLOkun/view?usp=drivesdk
И ещё ошибка что неинициализированная локальная переменная h i d

Comment: Да хоть немного же поработайте головой!!!!! Как мёд — так ложкой? Может, за вас еще к преподу сходить и сдать, а дома полы помыть?!!

Comment: Ну хоть скажите где неправильно ? Мне эту работу завтра надо сдать , пожалуйста , я уже много перегуглил

Comment: @Тимофій Вознюк Перечитайте комментарий с жирным шрифтом.